# Fabric2 tasks and dependencies

Tags: python, fabric, python-fabric-2

How can I define dependencies between tasks correctly using [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.5/)?

Given the following `fabfile.py`:

```
from fabric.tasks import task


@task
def clean(c):
    print(type(c))


@task(pre=[clean])
def deploy(c):
    print(type(c))
```

Running this `fabfile.py` using `fab2` results in:

```
$ fab2 -H example.org deploy
<class 'invoke.context.Context'>
<class 'fabric2.connection.Connection'>
```

Why is the the first argument to the `clean` task different from the first argument to `deploy`? I would have expected that a `fabric2.connection.Connection` instance is passed to each of them.

How would I run commands remotely in `clean`?

Comment: Maybe run `clean(c)` in `deploy()` without using `pre=[clean]`

Comment: fabric issues [pre-task ingores hosts and executes on localhost #1968](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1968) and [fabric issues a local command instead of remote on run() #1890](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1890)